# RDF/XML Ontology: Convert into JSON(-LD) Tree in Java

Tags: java, json, rdf, ontology, protege

I am trying to process an existing ontology (OWL 2.0) stored in the RDF/XML format created using Protégé to a JSON/JSON-LD tree representation in Java. The goal is to use this processed data in a separate vue.js web application for visualization purposes.

Unfortunately, I am struggling to get this done.

#### Data I am trying to process:

Here's the ontology I am trying to process (example ontology):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="urn:absolute:example.com/"
     xml:base="urn:absolute:example.com/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#CPU -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#CPU">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Enduser_Application -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Enduser_Application">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Software"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#GPU -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#GPU">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#HDD -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#HDD">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Storage"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Keyboard -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Keyboard">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Mainboard -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Mainboard">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Monitor -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Monitor">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Mouse -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Mouse">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Operating_System -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Operating_System">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Software"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Printer -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Printer">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Peripherals"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#SSD -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#SSD">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Storage"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Software -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Software"/>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Storage -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Storage">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Hardware"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Video_Game -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Video_Game">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Enduser_Application"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- urn:absolute:example.com/#Word_Processor -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:absolute:example.com/#Word_Processor">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:absolute:example.com/#Enduser_Application"/>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Here is the structure I want to turn this ontology into (preferably in JSON or JSON-LD):

[Protégé Screenshot (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofr4w.png)

```
Thing
|-- Hardware
  |-- CPU
  |-- GPU
  |-- Mainboard
  |-- Peripherals
    |-- Keyboard
    |-- Monitor
    |-- Mouse
    |-- Printer
  |-- Storage
    |-- HDD
    |-- SSD
|-- Software
  |-- Enduser_Application
    |-- Video_Game
    |-- Word_Processor
  |-- Operating_System
```

The ontology is however defining the exact opposite relation between classes with their subclassOf attributes. Thus, things seem to get more difficult.

#### Previous approaches

I've already tried a few different approaches.

1. Using Apache Jena

   ```
   Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
   model.read(ontology, "OWL");
   model.write(new BufferedWriter(f), "JSON-LD");
   ```

   This seems to work "best" currently. I eventually get a String containing JSON-LD data in a tree representation. The class relationships are inverted, though:

   For instance, the top layer consists of the elements Keyboard, Monitor, Mouse, Printer, and so on. Their respective superclasses are attached as child elements.

If there's a way to reverse the relationships using Apache Jena, that'd be pretty cool. I currently can't think of a possible way though.

2. Using owlapi

   For some reason owlapi would not work at all for me. It continously failed at parsing my ontology.
3. Using JSON-LD Framing (using the output from approach 1)

   I noticed that JSON-LD has a so-called 'framing' feature which essentially allows you to re-fit data into a defined skeleton.

   I tinkered around with JSON-LD's `@reverse` keyword in conjunction with `rdfs:subclassOf` hoping to essentially have the relationship reversed. However, I can't get that to work either and I am not exactly experienced in JSON-LD. Hence, I am somewhat struggling.

This has led to some sleepless nights for me already. I'd be SO happy if someone knows a solution to this or just can give me hints on how to solve this problem.

Thank you very, very much in advance.

Comment: What error did you get from owlapi? It should work and allow the same output as Jena. However the axioms being the wrong way around for your needs can only be changed in your code - no library will reverse them, as the subclass axioms are structured that way in owl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and I have indeed been able to load your ontology using the OWL API and save it into JsonLD format. Though, I doubt it will solve your problem as @Ignazio pointed out. In order to print out the tree structure you need access to a reasoner from which you can query subsumption relations.

Here is a code sample loading and saving your ontology and printing it in a tree structure.

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(owl.api.test.StandaloneOWLNamedIndividualRetrievalv5.AppHardwareTest.class);
// Why This Failure marker
private static final Marker WTF_MARKER = MarkerFactory.getMarker("WTF");

static OWLReasoner reasoner;

static void printChildren(NodeSet<OWLClass> owlClasses) {
    for (Node<OWLClass> node : owlClasses) {
        logger.trace(node.getRepresentativeElement().toString());
        if (!node.getRepresentativeElement().isBottomEntity())
            printChildren(reasoner.getSubClasses(node.getRepresentativeElement()));
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Setup physical IRI for storing ontology
        Path path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        IRI loadDocumentIRI = IRI.create("file:" + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/hardware.owl");
        IRI saveDocumentIRI = IRI.create("file:" + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/hardwareSave.txt");

        // Initialize
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(loadDocumentIRI);

        // Write to JsonLD format
        OWLDocumentFormat ontologyFormat = new RDFJsonLDDocumentFormat();
        manager.saveOntology(ontology, ontologyFormat, saveDocumentIRI);        

        // Print tree structure
        OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new JFactFactory();
        reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology);            
        Node<OWLClass> top = reasoner.getTopClassNode();
        logger.trace(top.getRepresentativeElement().toString());
        printChildren(reasoner.getSubClasses(top.getRepresentativeElement()));          
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error(WTF_MARKER, t.getMessage(), t);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: How could I set `RDFJsonLDDocumentFormat` to `Compact`, `Flattened` or `Framed` mode? could you point out a Documentation/Example?